# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 5079973: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, character-encoding, brute-force

I have a code that kind of hashing and I'm trying to brute force it by trying the ["rockyou" password list](https://www.kaggle.com/wjburns/common-password-list-rockyoutxt) .
I need to decode this string `2e84cb5f6c34b0a38fcdf99749` but I get the following error after 5m tries:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 5079973: invalid continuation byte
```

```
def GGGGotate(lol):
    bit = lol << 1
    movebit = bit & 255
    if (lol > 127 ):
        movebit = movebit | 1
    return (movebit)
t=4

list= open("password.txt").read().splitlines()
print(list)
c=0

while t== 4:


        # value = input("Enter your value: ")
        value=list[c]
        print(value)
        ListMoveBit = []
        Index_Move_bit = 1
        Index_Value = 0
        ORD_value = []
        ORD_key = []
        Under_10 = []
        Index_star = 0
        Final_encrypted = ""
        Passs = []
        List_values_back = []
        Uncrypt = []
        for i in value:
            ORD_value.append(ord(i))

        a = ord("a")
        ORD_key.append(a)
        lol = int(ORD_key[0]) ^ int(ORD_value[0])
        print(lol)
        ListMoveBit.append(GGGGotate(lol))
        for chars in ORD_value:
            if Index_Value == 0:
                Index_Value += 1
                pass
            else:
                lol = int(ListMoveBit[Index_Value-1]) ^ int(chars)
                ListMoveBit.append(GGGGotate(lol))
                Index_Value += 1
        for i in ListMoveBit:
            Under_10.append("0")
        for i in ListMoveBit:
            if (i < 9):
                Under_10[Index_star] = "1"
            Index_star += 1
        for i in ListMoveBit:
            x = hex(i)
            val = x[2:]
            if(i > 9) and (i < 16):
                Final_encrypted = Final_encrypted + "0" + val
            else:
                if (i<10):
                    Final_encrypted = Final_encrypted +"0"+val
                else:
                    Final_encrypted = Final_encrypted + val
        print("\nThe encrypted message is:")
        print(Final_encrypted + "\n")
        c=c+1
        print(c)
        if Final_encrypted =='2e84cb5f6c34b0a38fcdf99749':
            print (value)enter code here
            break
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Please consider sharing _full_ traceback in your [mcve] (use the [edit] button).